# ESET NOD32 does not scan files in shared folder Virtual Box guest

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, shared-folders, nod32, eset

I have installed **ESET NOD32** to a **Windows 10** *VirtualBox 6.0.6* guest machine. The update is complete and its latest version (12.1.34.0) is running. I am able to manually scan the local Windows drive (`C:`) without problems. But, I cannot scan a drive, say `H:`, that is mapped to my host's (**Ubuntu 19.04**) home folder (`/home/my_user`) which is defined as a "*shared folder*" in VirtualBox: The scan completes immediately with 0 scanned objects. Here is the scan log:

```
Log
Scan Log
Version of detection engine: 19645 (20190707)
Date: 07/07/2019  Time: 1:42:37 PM
Scanned disks, folders and files: H:\
Number of scanned objects: 0
Number of detections: 0
Time of completion: 1:42:37 PM  Total scanning time: 0 sec (00:00:00)
```

I have tried other shared folders (smaller and larger) with **read-only** permissions or **full** permissions. I even tried to scan directly a sub-folder of a mapped shared folder (like: `H:\Documents`) and I got the same result:

```
Log
Scan Log
Version of detection engine: 19673 (20190712)
Date: 12/07/2019  Time: 11:00:41 AM
Scanned disks, folders and files: H:\Documents
Number of scanned objects: 0
Number of detections: 0
Time of completion: 11:00:41 AM  Total scanning time: 0 sec (00:00:00)
```

The scan always completes with zero scanned objects, even though there are plenty of ordinary files in the shared folder.

I assume that these drives should be treated as *Network drives* by NOD32, which is an enabled option in NOD32 Setup.

Please note that, other applications in the guest (Windows 10) machine can access the files and sub-folders on the drive(s) mapped to the shared folder(s) and this is not a permission problem.

Please also note that, when I select **Custom Scan** and then go to one of the shared folder's drive, select some files from a (sub)folder, then NOD32 *can* scan those specific files. The problem is that NOD32 cannot "find" files in selected folders. In other words, NOD32 seems not be able to get the list of files in such "network" drives.

Comment: As the Linux disk is not in NTFS format, but is mapped to become a virtual NTFS disk, I suppose that the virtualization is missing some advanced disk functions that NOD32 is using, so that the scan ends with no objects found. Why don't you use Linux NOD32 for scanning Linux volumes?

Comment: I had some problems running NOD32 on Ubuntu ( https://forum.eset.com/topic/19097-new-linux-installation-virus-database-not-updating/ ). And finally I decided to switch to *clamav* there. On Windows, I remember I was able to scan network drives, on my work computer (this was more than 5 years ago). Now, at home, I do not have any network to test *real* **network drives**, but I assume that VirtualBox **shared drives**, should look similar to a (say) Linux NFS share, mapped as a drive on Windows.

Comment: Not necessarily the same. But you can certainly create a network share on the host and access it from the guest, if both are on the same network.

Comment: just an idea.  Could you try to scan a directory one level below root?  e.g. h:\some_dir?  What does it return?

Comment: Tested that. Nothing changed. Updated my original post.

Comment: Which version of VirtualBox are you using?  Are you using suspend?  Could you try to turn off the virtual machine with Win10, switch it on, map the drive and scan it right afterwards?

Comment: VirtualBox 6.0.6_Ubuntu r129722. Never using suspend. I turned on Win10, mapped a new drive to a new shared folder full of files and just scanned it. Again `Number of scanned objects: 0`

Comment: I have noticed some with the shared folders in the VB 6.x.  It can also be a bug in NOD32.  As a workaround I would suggest running Samba on Ubuntu and have it shared directory via network.  Then map the Samba network drive within the windows 10 installation via network.  Excluding the shared drive functionality.